# C# Keys.Apps will always open Windows context menu

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, keyboard

I'm trying to handle the Apps/Context Menu key on the keyboard. The key should be catched at a TextBox and then should show the programmed ContextMenuStrip of a DataGridView object.

However getting the ContextMenuStrip displayed turned out pretty simple. My only problem is that the flag `e.Handled = true` does not seem to work to prevent the Windows default context menu for the TextBox to appear. So it's opening the ContextMenuStrip for the DataGridView **and** the default context menu for the TextBox.

Following code applies:

```
void EditSearchField_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Apps)
  {
    // ContextMenuStrip is shown here
    DataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip.Show(DataGridView1, new Point(0, 0));
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
}
```

The result looks rather unpleasant. `KeyPreview = true` is also set.

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: This will happen when the cell is in edit mode, technically you are not supposed to monkey with the textbox' context menu.  I have no way to check this, Apple-encumbered.  Use the PreviewKeyDown event instead.  If that still doesn't work then override the form's ProcessCmdKey() method.

Comment: Tried with PreviewKeyDown but it seems I can't set something like `Handled` there. No good results with `ProcessCmdKey()` as well:
  
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
      if (!(keyData == Keys.Apps))
      {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
      }
  
      return true;
    }

Still same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ProcessCmdKey()` and `PreviewKeyDown()` didn't do the job, I decided to take another approach...

I found a (at least for my needs) decent workaround for my problem. In the "designer" portion of my form i defined a new ContextMenuStrip for my TextBox:

```
// editSearchField
[...]
this.editSearchField.ContextMenuStrip = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenuStrip();
```

This resulted in the Windows default context menu not showing anymore. Since the ContextMenuStrip has no ToolStripMenuItems it is discarded immediately.

For completeness, here's how I changed the `KeyDown()` function

```
void EditSearchField_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Apps)
  {
    if (dgvClients.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
      // force the selected row to be visible, or else we could get a .NET debugger
      dgvClients.CurrentCell = dgvClients.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0];

      // prepare context menu (disable inaccessible entries)
      Point ptMouse = dgvClients.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, dgvClients.SelectedRows[0].Index, false).Location;
      var mouseEvtArgs = new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Right, 1, 0, 0, 0);
      var mouseDgvArgs = new DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(0, dgvClients.SelectedRows[0].Index, ptMouse.X, ptMouse.Y, mouseEvtArgs);
      DgvClientsMouseDown(dgvClients, mouseDgvArgs);

      // calculate location for the context menu and finally show it
      Point ptContextMenuPos = dgvClients.PointToScreen(ptMouse);
      ptContextMenuPos.X += dgvClients.Width / 2;
      ptContextMenuPos.Y += dgvClients.RowTemplate.Height / 2;
      dgvClients.ContextMenuStrip.Show(ptContextMenuPos);
    }
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** fixed a bug within the code